# Is there a way to escape a keyword in a Gherkin feature or scenario description?

Tags: gherkin

In Gherkin, you can have free-form text that describes a scenario, a feature, etc. These descriptions are not used by, say, a test runner, but are for you to describe important additional information to another human.

[The documentation for Gherkin](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/) says that these cannot start a line with one of the other keywords, such as `Given`, `When` or `Then`. Yet, sometimes the best description I could give would be to start with one of these keywords.

I'm sort of making this up as I go here, but here is an example of what I *wish* I could do:

```
Scenario: Many notifications at the same time get combined

    When we have a lot of notifications being posted at once, it causes problems
    for humans. They can't make sense of that much new information all at once.
    So if we are ever in a situation where we are posting lots of
    notifications in a short time period, we will take the one with the highest
    severity and show it with the other notifications as "child" notifications,
    accessible via a link that says, "And N other issues."

    Given a notification posted today at 11:03:25
      And a notification posted today at 11:03:26
      And a notification posted today at 11:03:26
      And a notification posted today at 11:03:27
     When a notification is posted at 11:03.28
     Then the notification list will contain 1 notification
      And that notification should contain 4 child notifications
```

The problem I have is that because my description starts with a `When`, it the tools assume that I've started my specific steps, and blows up on the next line, which doesn't start with a keyword.

I've considered:

- **Commenting out the first line** or the entire description (that seems more consistent to me) but to me, there is a semantic difference between a comment with `#` and a description.
- **Rewording the thing to not start with a "When".** For example, if it started with, "In times where we have a lot of notifications..." but that's less readable, which is the point with Gherkin-style specifications.
  If it wasn't the first word in the whole description, I might be able to get away with simply wrapping my lines differently so that the "When" starts in the middle of a line instead of the beginning, but in this case, I don't have that option.

Those options just seem like workarounds that feel sub-optimal.

Is there a way to "escape" these keywords to tell the system that some usage of "When" is really still just part of the description and not a keyword? If not, is there some sort of accepted best practice or guideline for how people should handle situations like this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? The docs say you can have feature and scenario descriptions that begin with a gherkin keyword.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, that wasn't my interpretation of what I read (nor is it what I'm experiencing). The free-form text goes until you start a line with one of those keywords, at which point it treats it as the first step in the scenario. I did kind of have an example (a fragment of an example) in there before, but to help illustrate what I'm after, I fleshed it out quite a bit more. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: What happens if you write `When_ we` instead of `When we`? It's an existing convention in python that if the best name for something conflicts with a keyword, append an underscore to the name, and I've never seen an established convention for dealing with this in any other language (even though it comes up in most if not all languages.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use # in the beginning of the line (it's used for writing comments).

Ex:

```
# When a notification is posted...
```

Comment: I had considered that, but to me the description and a comment with `#` felt semantically different from each other, and I didn't want to conflate the two. If a person went with this, would you recommend putting the `#` on every line in the description? On every line in every description in all scenarios, features, and rules? Or just a one-time use?

Comment: You're adding a description by writing comments. :) You should use # on every line (wherever you put a description/comment in the feature file), otherwise a parser exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpretting the the language spec. You can describe a feature and use keywords at the beginning of a line. The example you posted gets interpreted as steps in a scenario since the description appears after the scenario keyword.

Just as Mr Cas said in his answer, you need comments.

```
Feature: Given a feature title
    When I use keywords up here
    Then it is allowed

Scenario: When I use keywords after the title to describe a scenario
    # Then I need to use comments
```